# Bicycle Storage Indoors

Tags: storage

I need to find a way to store my bike vertically parallel to the wall. However my ceilings are quite high so it would be difficult to lift it onto a ceiling mounted hook everyday. Is there anyway to have the hook extend further down or better yet a wall mounted solution?

Comment: Related: [What's the best way to lift a bike onto a storage hook?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/5350/8), [Is it really OK to hang a bicycle by the rear wheel from a hook?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/4204/8)

Comment: There are a number of pulley-bases bike storage systems.  Eg: https://www.rei.com/product/880249/delta-cycle-el-greco-ceiling-hoist-bike-storage?CAWELAID=120217890000849612&CAGPSPN=pla&CAAGID=21009510400&CATCI=pla-841188702192&cm_mmc=PLA_Google%7C404_1050549811%7C8802490001%7Cnone%7C06cb473e-a846-4a1c-88c2-27a2e891cbfc%7Cpla-841188702192&lsft=cm_mmc:PLA_Google_LIA%7C404_1050549811%7C8802490001%7Cnone%7C06cb473e-a846-4a1c-88c2-27a2e891cbfc&kclid=06cb473e-a846-4a1c-88c2-27a2e891cbfc&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIsL2U26HJ5QIVxR6tBh1EVwEjEAQYAiABEgKoLPD_BwE

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If by "parallel to the wall" you mean in the same direction as it would sit if it were leaning against the wall then you would probably do well with a rack like I bought when I moved into an apartment last year:

[image: Delta Michelangelo Rack]

This [Delta Michelangelo Rack](http://www.deltacycle.com/Michelangelo-2-Bike-Gravity-Storage-Rack) holds two bikes, requires only a single small screw hole in the wall to anchor, and does a good job of holding the bikes out of the way.  List is about $80 but I found mine on sale for around $55.  It also has a few clips/hangers for things like helmets.

I also have the pulley system recommended by @neil-fein,  but I find that if the bike is on the pulley, I rarely get it down.

Comment: This is nice. Can you hang it vertically?

Comment: The rack itself is designed to lean against the wall, and the upper arms are about as high as a normal person can reasonably lift a bike.  If you are trying to get the bike higher up the wall your best bet again is a pulley system.

Comment: @anton2g - You could probably hang it vertically if you use the seattube rather than top tube. For an option that doesn't need to be screwed to the wall look at floor to ceiling stands like this one: http://www.torpedo7.com.au/products/T7STCN92B/title/torpedo7-2-bike-floor-to-ceiling-stand

Answer (score 8):

Two things I've done in the past are to screw a hook like this into the wall:

[image: hook]

a little above the height of the front wheel hub when the bike is standing up, so I could just hook the front wheel to the wall, basically. In my case the hook is high enough up that the back tire of the bike is just off the ground, and is actually touching the wall, not the floor. The bike can be rotated on the hook to make it more parallel with the wall, up to the point where the pedal or the handlebar hits.

*edit:*

OK I guess my hooks in my shed are actually on the angled part of the roof, but in this picture I redrew where the hook *could* be, and then the back tire would rest on the floor.

[image]

I have also mounted a fork-mount to the wall and used that, but it means taking off the front wheel each time. It also makes the bike perpendicular to the wall, not parallel, unless you mount it to the side of a shelf or some piece of wood that comes away from the wall.

[image]

Here is my bike in the garage off the end of a shelf, parallel to the garage wall:

[image]

Comment: Does your first recommendation place the bike vertically?

Comment: I'll try to take a picture of my bike on the rack later today when I get home to give a better idea of what I mean...

Comment: edited my post to add pictures of my bikes hanging

Comment: The pictures really help. I guess to followup question, does putting a hook on the wall and hanging the bike as you showed damage the spokes or rim?

Comment: I would guess that no, it doesn't hurt. There was a discussion on that here: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4204/is-it-really-ok-to-hang-a-bicycle-by-the-rear-wheel-from-a-hook and my bikes have been hanging on hooks like that for a few years without harm. My 2 mountain bikes are in the 24-26 pound range, and that isn't a whole lot of weight for the wheels to have to hold up, really.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend that you take a good look at the Park Tools workstands. They are designed to support a single bike securely with grips that are easy enough to setup and release. Prices may be more than a DiY 'bit of wood' sticking out the wall, however, the workstand will have extra value for when you want to work on the bike. Plus, a Park Tool stand looks good, even if not in the workshop and in your front room.

Here are a few models that may be suited to your application:

http://www.parktool.com/product/deluxe-wall-mount-repair-stand-prs-4w-1

[image]

Clearly you will need a big bolt or two going through the wall to use the PRS-4W-1 or it's somewhat more deluxe cousin. The bike will be clamped 37cm from the wall.

http://www.parktool.com/product/team-issue-repair-stand-prs-25

[image]

The PRS-25 is a super-deluxe portable stand that packs away nicely. It has cheaper, more affordable cousins.

http://www.parktool.com/product/deluxe-home-mechanic-repair-stand-pcs-4-1

[image]

The PCS-4-1 Home repair stand does pack away neatly, but it is a bit heavier than the portable stand. The head twizzles around 360 degrees so you can put your bike on there, do up the clamp and spin it round to the vertical position.

With the Park Tool stands you can upgrade the clamps and get spare bits for them. They will not damage your bike.

As for getting one, try your local bike shop. They will probably only make a token effort at stocking repair stands, however, you can special order the desired model in after looking at what they have got. Postage on workstands can be significant, you won't have to pay that if ordering from your local bike shop.

If the idea of a workstand takes you, take a trip to http://www.parktool.com

Other makes of workstand will not be as iconic as the Park Tool offerings, neither are they likely to have replacement heads, however, price matters at times and you will almost certainly be able to find cheaper workstands with some hunting around.

Comment: Good idea... I hadn't thought of that, even though most nights I just slot my commuter into the work stand in the shed.

Comment: A work stand doesn't put the bike so high that it is out of the way - which is one very important reason for wanting to store the bike up at the wall.

Answer (score 3):

There are many such solutions available. You can purchase hooks that mount onto the wall and will hold a bike by its front wheel. If you wanted to use one of these, you'd need to attach something to the wall itself first to hang it off of, building up a structure with 2x4's.

[Here's an example](http://www.deltacycle.com/Leonardo-Single-Bike-Storage-Hook) of a wall-mounted hook. I've seen these for sale in many places, even in hardware stores.

However, there *are* ceiling-mounted bicycle holders that are built for high ceilings. These have a pulley system where you can lower the hooks to attach to the bicycle without lifting it at all, then pull the bike back up the ceiling. (In my experience, these racks are excellent for long-term storage, but they make it more of a hassle to get to the bike.)

Comment: The wall-mounted hook you showed is not parallel with the wall thus would take up too much room space in my place.

A pulley system is not really ideal for daily use

Comment: "Vertically parallel to the wall" means to me that the bike is positioned as if it were riding up the wall. If you mean flat against the wall, then perhaps you cold use one of these in a corner.

Comment: I'm guessing parallel to the wall means the opposite of what you think.  The picture in the example you link to would be what I would refer to as "perpendicular" to the wall.

Comment: @Kibbee - Yeah, I was thinking the direction of bike travel.

Comment: @anton2g - Knowing more about the space where you want to keep the bike would help. We're groping about a dark room with guesses at this point, but I think that some kind of free-standing solution would work best for you. Is mounting to the wall even an option? Keep in mind that mounting the bike flat against the wall like I think you're looking to do will still mean the handlebars are protruding.

Comment: I realize the handlebars will be protruding. It will probably be the best solution. I have to hang it in a small hallway. It has to be vertical because there is an entrance and a treadmill next to the space allocated to it. The ceiling is probably around 10 feet high. Kibbee is right with what I mean by parallel.

Comment: So you need something like [this](http://www.cycle-works.com/product_info.php?prod_id=48)?

Comment: That is a perpendicular bike. I want to hang it parallel to the wall.

Comment: Is image 6 on that link what you had in mind?

Comment: That is sorta what I had in mind but it looks like the red bar comes out from the wall quite a bit.

Comment: No further than most handlebars, I think.

Answer (score 1):

#### S-Hooks

For the lazies or if you need a quick "no-commitment" solution.

**Tip:** get it **"PVC coated"** so that it does not scratch the paint off your bicycle nor from whatever you hang it to

Regarding the specific context of this question: you'll need to have something in the wall to hook this to.

[image: S Hook PVC coated]

Answer (score 1):

Lots of the answers above look quite large/expensive (apart from the hooks), try taking a look at CLUGs.
https://getclug.com/

They are very cheap, very small, and can easily be removed etc.

Comment: This answer has been voided by age and the link-rot fairy.  The remote website has vanished, and the remaining parts of this answer have insufficient information to give any useful answer to a reader only 2 years after the answer was given.   This is why **we really don't like link-only answers**.  Instead, please use [edit] to add any information that you can remember about what this was and how it worked.

Answer (score 1):

> However my ceilings are quite high so it would be difficult to lift it onto a ceiling mounted hook everyday. Is there anyway to have the hook extend further down or better yet a wall mounted solution?

When living in a small flat with high ceilings I stored my guest bike on a hook quite far up to have it out of the way by having a pulley up there and using a rope to pull up and lower the bike.

My installation had the bike vertical and perpendicular to the wall with the hook (like the upper picture in [rally25rs' answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/6073/7450)) but it was anyways in a corner, so parallel to the other wall.  I've seen similar installations with 2 pulleys that put the bike up in a horizontal position parallel to the wall (over the entrance door). Parallel to the wall and vertical is possible as well.

Where I am, it's often easier to safely fix a hook to the wall where you want it than to the ceiling.